# Min and Max operations on enum values

Tags: c#

Using C#, how can I take the min or max of two enum values?

For example, if I have

```
enum Permissions
{
    None,
    Read,
    Write,
    Full
}
```

is there a method that lets me do `Helper.Max(Permissions.Read, Permissions.Full)` and get `Permissions.Full`, for example?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy enough to write a quick function that takes two of these as a parameter and compares them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Enums implement `IComparable` so you can use:

```
public static T Min<T>(T a, T b) where T : IComparable
{
    return a.CompareTo(b) <= 0 ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: Didn't consider that they might implement `IComparable` - this does the trick properly.

Comment: Crashes when a is null. Fix: Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(a, b)

Answer (score 4):

Since enums are convertible to integer types, you can just do:

```
   var permissions1 = Permissions.None;
   var permissions2 = Permissions.Full;
   var maxPermission = (Permissions) Math.Max((int) permissions1, (int) permissions2);
```

Note that this *could* cause issues if your enum is based on an unsigned type, or a type longer than 32 bits (i.e., long or ulong), but in that case you can just change the type you are casting the enums as to match the type declared in your enum.

I.e., for an enum declared as:

```
enum Permissions : ulong
{
    None,
    Read,
    Write,
    Full
}
```

You would use:

```
   var permissions1 = Permissions.None;
   var permissions2 = Permissions.Full;
   var maxPermission = (Permissions) Math.Max((ulong) permissions1, (ulong) permissions2);
```

Comment: What if the enum is based on `long`?

Comment: @Oded Then the compiler warning should indicate that pretty clearly and the fix is trivial...

Comment: @Obed, you would just change the type of your cast to `long`.

Comment: @Servy - Not in a generic function, which the answer by the OP indicates is what they are after.

Answer (score 3):

can be called with 2 or more parameters

```
    public static T GetMaxEnum<T>(params T[] enums) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (enums.Length < 2)
        {
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException();
        }
        return enums.Max();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with because I couldn't find anything in .NET that did this.

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static T Min<T>(T a, T b)
    {
        return (dynamic)a < (dynamic)b ? a : b;
    }

    public static T Max<T>(T a, T b)
    {
        return (dynamic)a > (dynamic)b ? a : b;
    }
}
```

Comment: You _could_ cast to the enumeration underlying type (getting it via the `Enum.GetUnderlyingType`), and do your min/max on that.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is quite old, it shows up at the top for some searches I did, so here we go, with a little more detail than the existing answer:

```
Permissions p1 = Permissions.Read;
Permissions p2 = Permissions.Write;

var pMax = (Permissions)Math.Max( (int)p1, (int)p2 );
```

Alternatively in case the enum is long based:

```
var pMax = (Permissions)Math.Max( (long)p1, (long)p2 );
```

Why does this work?

- `enum` values can be cast to `int` (or 'long'), which represents their position
- An `int` can be cast back to an `enum`
- `Math.Max()` apparently works on `int`

Sidenotes:

- Appearently this also works for the mininum with `Math.Min()`
- `IEnumerable.Max()` and `IEnumerable.Min()` can be used if you need the maximum or minimum of more than two `enum` values (if you don't mind `System.Linq`).

Answer (score -1):

I think you want something like this:

```
public enum Enum1
{
    A_VALUE,
    B_VALUE,
    C_VALUE
}

public enum Enum2
{
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2,
    VALUE_3
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();

        Console.WriteLine(p.EnumMin<Enum1>());
        Console.WriteLine(p.EnumMax<Enum2>());

    }


    T EnumMin<T>()
    {
        T ret; ;
        Array x = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        ret  = (T) x.GetValue(0);
        return ret;
    }

    T EnumMax<T>()
    {
        T ret; ;
        Array x = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        ret = (T)x.GetValue(x.Length-1);
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: Definitely not the question.

Answer (score -1):

There is a one-stop means for getting the min and max for any enumeration.  All it assumes is that the representation type is an `int`.

```
    public Tuple<int,int> GetMinMaxOfEnumeration<T>()
    {
        if (!typeof (T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enumeration");
        }
        var valuesAsInt = Enum.GetValues(typeof (T)).Cast<int>().OrderBy(n => n).ToArray();
        return new Tuple<int, int>(valuesAsInt.First(), valuesAsInt.Last());
    }
```

Comment: Not the question.